# Return value of an Angular Directive and based on value have ng-if to display content

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive, angular-controller

I have a Directive that returns a 0 or 1

```
 <my-code inputcode="{{ data.valBit }}"></my-code>
```

So `data.valBit` will be a 0 or 1

If it is a 1 , then I want it to display an HTML section of code,  how can I do that?  Problem with returning all the html from the directive is that it is put of a form along with ngmessage validation , so it is not fun to pass form or mess with link or compiler

```
<div ng-if="data.valBit == 1">
    part of my form,  with ngmessage etc...   $error  etc... 
    .......
</div>
```

Is this possible to get a callback from a directive that I can evaluate and decide whether to show or hide a section of html?

Comment: ?  what is that mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most simple way to do it is taking advantage of *two way data binding*. 
In Your case, the problem is that your are passing to the directive the evaluated value instead of the variable. 
**Just remove the braces in your directive argument** `<my-code inputcode="data.valBit"></my-code>`.

Example: ([PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/UJd39gbexFGacBC7DhcV))

**HTML**

```
<my-code inputcode="data.valBit"></my-code>
<p ng-if="data.valBit == 1">
  part of my form,  with ngmessage etc... $erroretc... 
</p>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
app.directive('myCode', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      inputcode: "=" //two way binding
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      scope.inputcode = 1;
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey a co-worker posted an issue that you might be able to see the problem , thx    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43376326/angular-directive-1-way-binding-is-working-but-2-way-binding-is-not