# Angular directive 1 way binding is working but 2 way binding is not

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

1. I am not using scope in my controller as i use controller as etc..
2. I have proof of concept that plunker without scope is working
3. 1 way binding is working
4. 2 way binding is NOT working  - shows literal value

**HTML page WORKING**

```
 Here: {{detail.program.ldcCode}}  SHOWS   "Here: PNLC"
 <lcd-code code="{{detail.program.ldcCode}}"></lcd-code>
```

Above passes in 1 way binding of that object/value of PNLC to Directive !

Directive :

```
 return {
        replace: true,
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            code: "@"
        },
         link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log('ldcCode', attrs.code);  // PRINTS out PNLC
```

Thus the above 1 way binding works with passing in `{{detail.program.ldcCode}}` as an expression , and then in directive the `code: "@"`    along with console.log of `console.log('ldcCode', attrs.code);`  **// PRINTS out PNLC**

**So HERE IS THE PROBLEM,  when i switch to my much needed two way data binding**

Next is the issue:

**Pass from HTML to directive WITHOUT Expression**

```
<lcd-code code="detail.program.ldcCode"></lcd-code>
```

**Directive**

```
scope: {
      code : "="
},
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log('ldcCode', attrs.code);
           LITERALLY this prints to chrome dev console as below in bold
```

**ldcCode detail.program.ldcCode**

What is going on?

Comment: So it's behaving like it's a string binding (@). It's like something didn't get saved right. Try a one-way arrow (<) binding. Everything you've posted looks correct

Comment: Don't us `{{ }}` interpolation in Angular expressions. They are problematic in attribute `@` bindings. Don't work with two-way `=` bindings.

Comment: So what am I doing wrong,  don't do {{}} and the =  does not work

Comment: Two-way `=` binding works. People use it everyday.

Comment: oh, do i need to use  scope.code  instead of attrs.code ?

Comment: Yes, in both cases that you are asking for, you have to use `scope.code` and you don't have to use interpolation {{}} in the directive parameters. I can post an answer to clarify it if you still have doubts...

Comment: I had to use scope.code     attrs.code   ...which i guess makes sense but i was surprised how many other people seem to not say not to use  attrs.code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `attr` link function parameter is showing the raw value given to the attribute.

Angular, when using the isolated scope and the two way biding '=' operator, take that value and interpolate it on the parent scope to get the actual value that you can access via the scope parameter on the link function.

Reference to the [$compile.directive.Attributes](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes) in Angular docs:

> A shared object between directive compile / linking functions which
>   contains normalized DOM element attributes. The values reflect current
>   binding state {{ }}

If you want to get the interpolate value of the attribute, even not on the isolated scope, [you can use the $observe method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) on it:

```
function linkingFn(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
  // get the attribute value
  console.log(attrs.ngModel);

  // change the attribute
  attrs.$set('ngModel', 'new value');

  // observe changes to interpolated attribute
  attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(value) {
    console.log('ngModel has changed value to ' + value);
  });
}
```